# How do I run script at boot inside an apk?

Tags: android, c, apk, decompiling

I have an apk that I decompile using apktool and I want to create a script and then place it inside the apk file before I recompile it and start it.

How do I do this?

I just want to know what type of file should I place inside my apk folder so that the app will run with the file I implanted? How do I do this. Can someone please help me?

Comment: Android apps don't run scripts at all. If you want to change functionality of the app you have to learn Smali language and modify the Smali code. Also Android API knowledge and some Java skills are essential.

Comment: You may better check if your "script" may be easier to realize using a separate app like "Tasker".